# Python - image watermark

Tags: python-3.x, watermark

my goal is to create a watermark image, based on a logo (TIF format) and a background image (JPG).
I'm using this code:

```
from PIL import Image 
def watermark_with_transparency(input_image_path,
                                output_image_path,
                                watermark_image_path,
                                position):
    base_image = Image.open(input_image_path)
    watermark = Image.open(watermark_image_path)
    width, height = base_image.size

    transparent = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (0,0,0,0))
    transparent.paste(base_image, (0,0))
    transparent.paste(watermark, position, mask=watermark)
    transparent.show()
    transparent.save(output_image_path)
```

Watermark image is a trasparent TIF.
If I run above code, watermark result does not include any logo.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors? I tried this and it pasted fine (had to solve Error bad transparency mask)

Comment: Hi, no errors at all, simply no watermark is applied. what do you mean by bad trasparency mask? - thx

Comment: My loaded image was not RGBA so it complained and I had to convert it, after that it worked. I get watermark pasted over the base image and it is saved correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw, ImageFont

path=r'/home/anuj/FIle_server/production/AI_PROJECT/SEQ_001/sq1/frm_seq_v001.001.jpeg'  #This is path of your image
demo_image = Image.open(path)
img_width, img_height =demo_image.size
draw_image = ImageDraw.Draw(demo_image)
text_image ="HQVFX" #Here you can assign your watermark.

font_image =ImageFont.truetype('/home/anuj/FIle_server/task/WaterBrush-Regular.ttf',50)
text_width, text_height = draw_image.textsize(text_image,font_image)

font_margin = 10

x = img_width - text_width - font_margin
y = img_height - text_height - font_margin

draw_image.text((x,y), text_image, font= font_image)
demo_image.show()

demo_image.save("watermark.jpg")
```